# CSLA: List item must be marked as a child object

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, csla

I have two tables Survey and SurveyQuestion. I'm trying to save multiple questions to one Survey. I'm using

```
@(Html.BeginCollectionItem("SurveyQuestions")){ }.
```

When I click on Save, it says 'List item must be marked as a child object'. Any idea where I need to do that?

When calling the PartialView, I'm marking it as a child but still it does not work.

```
return PartialView("_questionForm", SurveyQuestion.New(true));

public static SurveyQuestion New(Boolean isChild = false)
    {
        SurveyQuestion d = DataPortal.Create<SurveyQuestion>();
        if (isChild)
            d.MarkAsChild();
        return d;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder was not set in the Global.asax